# What to say when you want to ask a model to imitate a pose from an artwork

Tags: phrase-request

[image]

Say the woman on the left is my model for drawing, and I want to ask her to take the position as shown above, the same pose Mona Lisa is in.

Do I say to her:

> "I would like you to pose as in Leonardo da Vinci's artwork *Mona Lisa*."

or is there a more concise and natural way to say it?

Comment: I guess it will look more natural if you say "I would like you to pose as Mona Lisa in Leonardo da Vinci's artwork/painting(whatever)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggestion is fine, although it has a slightly formal air if spoken.

Some more conversational alternatives:

"Could you pose like the woman in the *Mona Lisa*?"

"Just pretend you're the woman in the *Mona Lisa*"

"Could you copy the pose of the woman in the *Mona Lisa*?"

Or, since you presumably have a copy of the *Mona Lisa* to show them, you could just hold that up and say:

"Could you pose just like that?"

Answer (score 1):

A more formal way of saying this is: "Please *adopt* the pose seen in the Mona Lisa". *Assume* could also be used there, or even "strike".

P.S. But there is nothing wrong with the more conversational choices.